# Contact form send buttons throwing errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs

I have created a contact form in React, now everything works right expect one thing. When the form is empty and I click send button it throws errors.

**Errors:**

```
{ "message": "Network Error"
, "name": "Error"
, "stack": "Error: Network Error\n at createError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16606:15)\n at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16149:14)"
, "config":
  { "url": "https://formcarry.com/s/Ek8wZYC7v0H"
  , "method": "post"
  , "data": "{\"name\":\"\",\"surname\":\"\",\"email\":\"\",\"message\":\"\"}"
  , "headers":
     { "Accept": "application/json"
     , "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
     }
  , "transformRequest": [null]
  , "transformResponse": [null]
  , "timeout": 0
  , "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN"
  , "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
  , "maxContentLength": -1
  }
}
```

**ContactPage.js (this is where I import the ContactForm.js):**

```
  <LayoutWrapperMain className={css.staticPageWrapper}>

  <h1 className={css.pageTitle}>Need help? Ask our experts for any help you need.</h1>

  <div className={css.contentWrapper}>

  <ContactForm />

  <GoogleMap />

  </div>

  </LayoutWrapperMain>
```

**ContactForm.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios"; // For making client request.

class ContactForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: "", surname: "", email: "", message: ""};
  }

  handleForm = e => {
    axios.post(
      "https://formcarry.com/s/Ek8wZYC7v0H", 
      this.state, 
      {headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}}
      )

      .then(function (response) {
        let successMessage = document.querySelector('.success-message');
        successMessage.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response.data.title);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        let errorMessage = document.querySelector('.error-message');
        errorMessage.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(error);
      });

    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({name: '', surname: '', email: '', message: ''}) // <= here
  }
    handleFields = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });  

  render() {
    return (

      <form onSubmit={this.handleForm}>
        <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" onChange={this.handleFields} value={this.state.name} />

        <label htmlFor="surname">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" onChange={this.handleFields} value={this.state.surname} />

        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" onChange={this.handleFields} value={this.state.email} />

        <label htmlFor="message">Your Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" onChange={this.handleFields} value={this.state.message}></textarea>

        <button id="how-button" type="submit">Send</button>

          <div className="success-message">
            <label></label>
          </div>

          <div className="error-message">
            <label></label>
          </div>

      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default ContactForm;
```

So the form works right and it throws success message the right way after all the fields are filled, but when the form is empty it throws the errors I posted.

What could the error be? **I have a website on live so you can test it on your own:**

https://trustmypetsitter.herokuapp.com/contact

Comment: When I test your contact form, I got both a "403 Forbidden" error from formcarry.com and a CORS policy error from the XMLHttpRequest. Can you provide more details about the error (maybe using directly an XMLHttpRequest might help)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to allow posting empty fields? A simple work around would be to make the fields required, such as:

```js
<input required type="text" id="name" name="name" onChange={this.handleFields} value={this.state.name} />
```

Answer (score 1):

The BE service is returning a 403 status code.

As for the error output on the page, it seems that you're printing the whole error object.

```
let errorMessage = document.querySelector('.error-message');
errorMessage.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(error);
```

Rather you should print just the message: `error.message`.

I would make sure to defend against empty states using the `required` attr on the input fields.

Here's some docs on form validation that might be useful: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation